# JQUERY - Send Array through Ajax to PHP (I know the issue has been treated a lot...)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I would like to send an array I created in my Jquery script to a php file. I know that question has been treated a lot. Unfortunately when applying what seems to be a best practice I do not manage to get it working. Hope someone can help me undertand. Thank you in advance. Cheers. Marc. Here below my code:

my js:

```
// I build myArray
var myArray = new Array();
$('.someClass').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    myArray.push({
        'id': $this.attr('attrId')
    });
});

//...and then send it to myFile.php
var ajaxData = { myArray: JSON.stringify(myArray) };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myFile.php",
    data: ajaxData,
    success: function(data) {
        $('body').append(data);
    }
});​
```

my php:

```
$myArray = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['myArray']));

foreach($myArray as $value){
    echo $value.'</br>';
}
```

the error I get:

```
Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
$myArray = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['myArray']));
```

With this:

```
$myArray = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['myArray']), true);
```

If the second parameter of json_decode() is set to true, all objects will be converted to associative arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Hello Jeroen. Thanks for trying to help. Applying what you suggest make me have no fatal error anymore but unfortunately instead of $value being printed out in my php foreach loop, I have 'Array' echoed out...

Comment: Try replacing `echo $value.'</br>';` with `print_r ($value);` and tell me what the output is

Comment: Ok great ! Thanks to your inputs I have it working like a charm. Thank you very much Jeroen. Whishing you a good day...